# Every keystroke in the Gnome Activities search bar opens a new terminal

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gsettings

I've been experiencing this weird behaviour for about a month and a half -- Every time a key is pressed within the Activities search bar of Gnome, a new Terminator tab is opened.

For instance, if I press (and release) the Super key, then type "hello", I will have a Terminator window with five new tabs (actually, not always five if I type fast enough - it seems to fire only at intervals while I type).

It must somehow be linked to my recent efforts to get the Calculator multimedia key of my keyboard mapped to `terminator --new-tab` instead of being mapped to opening the calculator app. However, despite removing all terminal-related keyboard shortcuts from my Gnome settings, the problem persists.

I don't remember exactly how I had attempted my Calculator key remap, but I do remember that I had eventually succeeded, perhaps by using CLI methods (I remember trying several recipes found on various forums, some of which involved `gsettings`), so there might be a clue there as to what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause of my problem.

I had overriden the default "gnome-calculator" by creating `~/.local/bin/gnome-calculator` with the following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
terminator --new-tab
```

I did this because Gnome wouldn't let me customize the keyboard shortcut for my keyboard's "calculator" key (which, by default, starts gnome-calculator).

I was unaware that gnome-calculator is not just the GUI, but also serves as the back-end for instant results when you type something in the Activities search (e.g. when you type "3+4" in the search bar, it calls `gnome-calculator --solve "3+4"`, which doesn't open the GUI but just echoes the result if it recognizes the expression).

So what I will do now is alter my `gnome-calculator` script: if called with `--solve`, it will just be a proxy to `/usr/bin/gnome-calculator`, otherwise, I will have it open a terminal.